# parse order and nested conditionals

Tags: conditionals, advanced-conditionals, parse

Can i nest simple conditionals and are nested simple conditionals still parsed early?

What happens when nesting an advanced conditional inside a simple conditional?

(wiki answer)

Answer (score 2):

the following template will generate an error because neither the "foo" or "bar" module or plugin exist.

**Nested simple conditionals**
The "foo" error will not show up, because the two nested conditionals are both simple conditionals.

**Advanced conditional**
The second block has a nested advanced conditional (it tests for two conditionals, last_segment AND segment_3) and thus the whole block is seen as being advanced conditionals, including the outer. The whole block will be parsed, generating an error for the non-existant "bar" extension.

Hands-on: Try removing the AND ... part from the advanced conditional to test the difference (no more error). And try adding foo/bar to the browser url (example.com/group/template/foo/bar), and see the "foo" error appear.

```
Conditional test
{if last_segment != "foo"}
  {if segment_3 == "foo"}
    {exp:foo}{/exp:foo}
  {/if}
{/if}

{if last_segment != "foo"}
  {if segment_3 == "foo" AND segment_3 =="bar"}
    {exp:bar}{/exp:bar}
  {/if}
{/if}
```

*Tip: Tags in advanced conditionals are always being parsed, they are just discarded before displaying the page. if you're not sure what is parsed, try enabling template-debugging to see which tags do get parsed. Alternatively you could add a tag for a non-existing plugin "foo" and see if the page generates an error, that way you know that the part is being parsed :-)*